# Uncaught Reference Error : newAge is not defined throws at "myPlaygroundLink"

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

The component I wanna create should recieve input from user and update `newAge` variable that I have defined and should console log it, but when I try to enter value this popup comes with error

> Uncaught Reference Error : newAge is not defined

Here is my HTML code

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Revise" style="width: 600px;">
        <lightning-input label="Enter New Age" value={newAge} onchange={handleChange}></lightning-input>
        Name : {animalName}
        <br />
        Age : {animalAge}
        <!-- <lightning-button label="Update Age" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button> -->
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

And here's my JS code

```javascript
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class Revise extends LightningElement {
    animalName = "King Kong";
    animalAge = 55;
    newAge = 0;
    handleChange(event)
        {
            this.newAge = event.target.value;
            console.log(this.newAge);
        }
    }
```